# Quickly fill a large file with integer value -1

Tags: java, java-io

The following very quickly creates large files filled with zeros. (This sample is in Scala but only the Java API is used)

```
val f = new File(dir, fileName)
val raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw")
raf.setLength(8 * math.pow(math.pow(2, 16), 2).toLong)
raf.close()
```

What is a quick way to fill the file with the integer value -1 (`0xffffffff`)?

Comment: Of course creating an empty binary file of a certain length is fast as 0 will be the default value set by the native memory allocator. Setting all the bits to 1 is bound to take longer. Did you try writing 0xff bytes to the file via memory mapping?

Comment: @Thomas What native memory allocator? Is disk space allocated with a default value?

Comment: No, I didn't @Thomas. That's not something I've heard of before. I'm just reading about it now and I think it will fit the bill.

Comment: @shmosel to be honest I'm not exactly sure but I'd hope so. Creating a file that contains whatever happens to be in the segments it occupies would be kind of risky. I'm also not sure that the file will actually be written by native code but given the fact that filesystems need to be handled on a per-plattform basis that's where just allocating disk space should go.

Comment: @shmosel the javadoc for `setLength` says the contents are undefined when the new length extends the file. FWIW, the code in this question is creating files filled with zero (on Java 8/Ubuntu/xfs/nvme).

Comment: You do know that `Math.pow(Math.pow(2, 16), 2)` is same as `Math.pow(2, 32)`, and that `8 * Math.pow(Math.pow(2, 16), 2)` is same as `Math.pow(2, 35)`, right? And that `Math.pow(2, 16)` is slow double math for the very fast `1 << 16` integer math? So `8 * math.pow(math.pow(2, 16), 2).toLong` is a very long way to say `1L << 35`.

Comment: @Andreas Actually, there are multiple files being written. The `16` is a variable and the `8` is for code readability (meaning 2 x int). I simplified the code for brevity. Yes, I know that I can precompute arithmetic operations. :)

Comment: @Synesso I wasn't talking about pre-computing anything. I was talking about using double math `Math.pow(2, x)` when `1L << x` will do the same in fast integer math.

Comment: @andreas That operation will be called exactly 17 times. As written, it is instantly grokkable in the domain of the app. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: @Synesso I don't know about "instantly grokkable". I had trouble figuring out that `8 * math.pow(math.pow(2, 16), 2).toLong` was supposed to mean 32 GiB.

Comment: Exactly how big is "big"?

Comment: @Andreas in the app domain, 32GB means nothing, 8 * 2^16^2 is meaningful.